# Error, warnings in while loop

Tags: r, while-loop, dataframe

I have a data-frame 'clean' which has 2 columns. For the purpose of processing only one column 'ID' is relevant. This column has numbers which are repeated multiple times. Output required is a new data frame with two columns one with unique id and another with number of times it appears.

The code runs OK but when I execute I get 50 warning messages as following:

```
50: In while (clean$ID == x) { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Following is my code. Can someone help understand and resolve this error?

```
  j <- unique(clean$ID)
  count=0
  for (x in j)
   {
     while (clean$ID==x)
      {
       count<-count+1
       }
    result<-append(result,x,count)
   }
 result
```

Comment: May you can try `as.data.frame(table(clean$ID))` instead of `while` loop?

Answer (score 1):

First, I will address the error. Note that `clean$ID` is a vector like `1:5` and you are comparing it to a single value, say `3` when you do `1:5==3`, you get a vector of logical values. So when you say `while(1:5==3)` what do you mean? Do you want while `any` of the values are true, or do you want to repeat while `all` values are true? The warning indicates the evaluation is only done based on the first value which is equivalent to `(1:5)[1]==3`

But as @arkun pointed out, you code is a poor strategy to accomplish your goal.

```
as.data.frame(table(clean$ID))
```

would be a much better choice to get a data.frame with the count of each ID value.